# Codegolf: Convert csv to HTML table with smallest amount of code in C#

Tags: c#, csv, code-golf

I'm adding a function to my own personal toolkit lib to do simple CSV to HTML table conversion.

I would like the **smallest possible piece of code to do this in C#**, and it needs to be able to handle CSV files in excess of ~500mb.

So far my two contenders are

- splitting csv into arrays by
  delimiters and building HTML output
- search-replace delimiters with table
  th tr td tags

Assume that the file/read/disk operations are already handled... i.e., i'm passing a string containing the contents of said CSV into this function.  The output will consist of straight up simple HTML style-free markup, and yes the data may have stray commas and breaks therein.

**update:**  some folks asked.   100% of the CSV i deal with comes straight out of excel if that helps.

#### Example string:

```
a1,b1,c1\r\n
a2,b2,c2\r\n
```

Comment: What assumptions can we make about the csv -- how are you handling commas or line breaks inside columns. If it's with quotes, how are you escaping the quotes? I know the right way, but that doesn't mean that will match how your csv looks.

Comment: Can you provide an example CSV string and row delimiter? (I'm assuming it's "\r\n")

Comment: Is the data guaranteed to be rectangular?  That is, are there the same number of items in each row?

Comment: Yes, if not the elements will be blank yet there will be a delimiter

Comment: But why "smallest possible piece of code". That's asking for the lowest quality. My main objection against CodeGolf.

Comment: its a pretty basic function.  If it meets functional/performance requirements while being tiny, i think quality will be more than sufficient

Comment: @NoCarrier - True, but imagine if you inherited the garbage that is my answer a year from now. It's short and works as per the requirements, but there is no exception handling, the formatting is awful, memory is abused, and it's difficult to read.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: CodeGolf is a learning exercise. While the code that results won't be production-quality, it's a great way to learn the capabilities and limitations of various languages.

Comment: @Nosredna: I get all that, but this question confuses the issue a little by wanting to add it to a Toolkit. And at the least the metric should count tokens, so that shortening names stops upping the score.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, You're right. But he could still learn a couple techniques he hadn't thought of and use them to write real production code.

Comment: code-golf questions should be community wiki

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read All Lines into Memory

```
    var lines =File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);
    using (var outfs = File.AppendText(args[1]))
    {
        outfs.Write("<html><body><table>");
        foreach (var line in lines)
            outfs.Write("<tr><td>" + string.Join("</td><td>", line.Split(',')) + "</td></tr>");
        outfs.Write("</table></body></html>");
    }
```

or Read one line at a time

```
    using (var inFs = File.OpenText(args[0]))
    using (var outfs = File.AppendText(args[1]))
    {
        outfs.Write("<html><body><table>");
        while (!inFs.EndOfStream )
            outfs.Write("<tr><td>" + string.Join("</td><td>", inFs.ReadLine().Split(',')) + "</td></tr>");
        outfs.Write("</table></body></html>");
    }
```

... @Jimmy ... I created an extended version using LINQ.  Here is the highlight ... (lazy eval for line reading)

```
    using (var lp = args[0].Load())
        lp.Select(l => "<tr><td>" + string.Join("</td><td>", l.Split(',')) + "</td></tr>")
        .Write("<html><body><table>", "</table></body></html>", args[1]);
```

Comment: Your second solution is by far the best so far because of the mentioned memory requirements. If the solution really does need to handle files on the order of 500MB, then storing the entire contents in memory is not really a good idea.

Comment: Yeah,  I wrote the first version for simplicity and then saw the new requirement so I figured I'd extend it.   Full features, clean, and still pretty short.  I'm thinking I could stuff in soem LINQ but then it would still try to load this all in memory.

Comment: if you wrap the Readlines() in a function that yield returns each line you could get the IEnumerable for LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

probably not much shorter you can get than this, but just remember that any real solution would handle quotes, commas inside of quotes, and conversions to html entities.

```
return "<table><tr><td>"+s
   .Replace("\n","</td></tr><tr><td>")
   .Replace(",","</td><td>")+"</td></tr></table>";
```

EDIT: here's (largely untested) addition of htmlencode and quote-matching. I htmlencode first, then all commas become '<' (which don't collide because the existing ones have been encoded already.

```
bool q=false;
return "<table><tr><td>"
  + new string(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s)
       .Select(c=>c=='"'?(q=!q)?c:c:(c==','&&!q)?'<':c).ToArray())
    .Replace("<", "</td><td>")
    .Replace("\n", "</td></tr><tr><td>")
  + "</td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: Chaining the .Replace(), nice - I was thinking of something like this originally but didn't know how to deal with the beginning and end rows - it's all so obvious now lol

Comment: well, the shorter the code-golf answer, the less useful it is, so you shouldn't have deleted your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun version using lambda expressions.  It's not as short as replacing commas with `"</td><td>"`, but it has it's own special charm:

```
var r = new StringBuilder("<table>");
s.Split('\n').ToList().ForEach(t => r.Append("<tr>").Append(t.Split(',').Select(u => "<td>" + u + "</td>")).Append("</tr>"));
return r.Append("</table>").ToString();
```

If I were to right this for production, I'd use a state machine to track nested quotes, newlines, and commas, because excel can put new lines in the middle of column.  IIRC you can also specify a different delimiter entirely.