# C# Multidimensional Arrays Like PHP

Tags: c#, arrays

I've been trying to do this for about 6 hours now and i'm stumped..

I want the equivalent of this in C#:

```
    $settings = array();
    foreach(file('settings.txt') as $l) $settings[]=explode(',',$l);
    print $settings[0][2];
```

This is what i've got so far that doesn't work:

```
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\" + "settings.txt";
    string[,] settings;

    FileStream file = null;
    StreamReader sr = null;

    try
    {
        file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
        sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.ASCII);
        string[] line;
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            settings[i++, 0] = line[0];
        } while (line != null);
        file.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(settings[1, 0]);
    } catch (Exception err) { MessageBox.Show(err.Message); }
```

I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", any ideas would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Can you post a few sample lines of settings.txt?

Comment: Which line do you get the exception?

Comment: It would help if you made it clear what the php does...

Comment: @Andrew: Its just csv: value,value,value,value,value,value
@Daniel: settings[i++, 0] = line[0];

Comment: It turns csv into an array:

{
  0 : {value,value,value,value,value,value},
  1 : {value,value,value,value,value,value},
  2 : {value,value,value,value,value,value},
  3 : {value,value,value,value,value,value}
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a *jagged array* instead of a multidimensional one – or better yet, a `List<string[]>`:

```
var settings = new List<string[]>();

foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("settings.txt", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
    settings.Add(line.Split(','));
```

Marc's use of LINQ instead of the loop is a good alternative.

Comment: I like this better than having to explicitly state your bounds.

Comment: You can even go nuts and use a Collection<Collection<string>> :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should initiate your array first, like that :

```
string[,] settings = new string[3,3];
```

**EDIT :** Also by this line, you skip to set first item of the array :

```
settings[i++, 0] = line[0];
```

You should assign your value like that :

```
settings[i, 0] = line[0];
i++;
```

Comment: then you should use a List<string> or ArrayList to store your lines.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to look at lots of different cells:

```
    string[][] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(
        line => line.Split(',').ToArray()).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(lines[0][2]);
```

If you **only** want [0][2], you can limit it a bit...

```
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
    { // only read the first line (zero)
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine().Split(',')[2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, that shouldn't even compile - you never initialize the value of `settings`. Arrays in .NET are of a fixed size - it looks to me like you should be using a `List<string[]>` instead:

```
List<string> settings = new List<string>();

using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        settings.Add(line.Split(','));
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(settings[1][0]); // Shows the first part of the second line
```

(Note that this also makes sure that the file gets closed even if exceptions occur - you should definitely learn about the `using` statement. Marc's solution avoids this by loading all the lines in a single call, which obviously has a memory overhead but is otherwise good.)

Comment: It was initialized outside of that code block because i need to access it from lots of different functions :)

Comment: Given that the way you initialize it is one of the important pieces of information, it would help if you'd present self-contained chunks of code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the super fast answers!!

I settled on:

```
    List settings = new List();
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("settings.txt", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)) settings.Add(line.Split(','));
```

Thanks!

Dean.

Answer (score 0):

There was a [code-golf question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966889/codegolf-convert-csv-to-html-table-with-smallest-amount-of-code-in-c) about a similar problem last week.  And by request I wrote a version that used LINQ. You can check it out on my [site](http://hackersbasement.com/?p=96).

You probably want to adapt it a bit for your needs...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string[][] lines = null;
        using (var lp = "settings.txt".Load())
            lines = lp.Select(l => l.Split(',')).ToArray();
}
```

http://hackersbasement.com/?p=96 (and just in case my site ever changes)

```
public static class LineProcessorLinq
{
    public static LineProcessor Load(this string fileName)
    {
        return new LineProcessor(fileName);
    }

    public static void Write(this IEnumerable<string> lines, string header, string footer, string fileName)
    {
        using (var fs = File.AppendText(fileName))
            lines.Write(header, footer, fs);
    }

    public static void Write(this IEnumerable<string> lines, string header, string footer, StreamWriter writer)
    {
        if (writer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
            writer.Write(header);

        foreach (var line in lines)
            writer.Write(line);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(footer))
            writer.Write(footer);
    }
}
public class LineProcessor : Component, IEnumerable<string>
{
    private StreamReader _reader = null;

    public LineProcessor(string fileName) : this(File.OpenText(fileName)) { }

    public LineProcessor(StreamReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
        _reader = reader;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && _reader != null)
            _reader.Close();
    }

    #region IEnumerable<string> Members

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var currentPos = _reader.BaseStream.Position;
        while (!_reader.EndOfStream)
            yield return _reader.ReadLine();
        if (_reader.BaseStream.CanSeek)
            _reader.BaseStream.Seek(currentPos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Members

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    #endregion
}
```